# How to verify optional substring in regex

Tags: java, android, regex

I have one regex which verify 14 character length.
but now i want to verify it could be multiply by 2 length.

my current regex is `"(0[0-1][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]0[0-2]0[0-4]0[0-2]0[0-2])"`

It accepts only 14 length string

```
match : `00000002000102 00000002000101`
do not match : `00 , 0000 , 00000200,`
```

I want to make accepts these above don't match strings also.

I explained you below what i want to do

**EDITED :**

Here i am going to explain again my requirements

See my String length would be 14 digits, now when in my String first 2 digits is compulsory.
my String have 6 different validation parts which i am going to mention below.

```
first part would be  : 00 or 01 only  : Sting length should be 2 only
second part would be : 0000-9999 any value between this.    : Sting length should be 6 only
third part would be  : 00 or 02 only             : Sting length should be 8 only
fourth part would be : 00 or 01 or 04 only even not 03.: Sting length should be 10 only
fifth part would be  : 00 or 01 or 02            : Sting length should be 12 only
sixth part would be  : 00 or 01 or 02            : Sting length should be 14 only
```

- So here when my input string contains compulsory first part.
- If it would contains 2nd part that it would compulsory 1st and 2nd
  both and both part should verified as per above validation.
- If string contains 3rd part also means it length should 8 and its
  includes first and second part then it would compulsory verifies
  1st,2nd and 3rd part as per above condition
- If string contains 4rd part also means its length 10 and its includes
  first and second and third part then it would compulsory verifies
  1st,2nd,3rd part and 4th part also as per above condition
- same like above continue up to 6th part.

Please help me and let me know what i have to change in my current reg ex implementation

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: in response to the specs in the edited question:**

Something like this; now it's really your homework ;)

```
^(0[0-1](?:[0-9]{4}(?:0[02](?:0[014](?:0[0-2](?:0[0-2])?)?)?)?)?)$
```

Comment: this regex will not verify my above validation

Comment: Edited : yes, actually,  it's an idea, not a turnkey solution

Comment: A non-capturing group, http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html . Also,  * and ?  could help. This may take some experimenting

Comment: I want to make every 2 digits length sub string make a optional expect first two digits are compulsory

Comment: @Sam_k: Now you seem to have all the building blocks and the spec.  I think you could try putting it together.  Are there any missing parts you need?

Comment: `[\d\d]` is effectively the same as `\d`

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of fourth group

> fourth part would be : 00 or 01 or 04 only even not 03.

is unclear. Do you need 02 here?

With 02 allowed in fourth part

```
/^((0[01])|(0[01][0-9]{4})|(0[01][0-9]{4}0[02])|(0[01][0-9]{4}0[02]0[0124])|(0[01][0-9]{4}0[02]0[0124]0[0-2])|(0[01][0-9]{4}0[02]0[0124]0[0-2]0[0-2]))$/
```

with 02 not allowed in fourth part

```
/^((0[01])|(0[01][0-9]{4})|(0[01][0-9]{4}0[02])|(0[01][0-9]{4}0[02]0[014])|(0[01][0-9]{4}0[02]0[014]0[0-2])|(0[01][0-9]{4}0[02]0[014]0[0-2]0[0-2]))$/
```

Please, note what your initial pattern accepted strings longer than 14 symbols, because you didn't used ^ and $

Comment: Check my Edited question you will get more idea